# How can I get actual value in AndroidManifest.xml using Androguard?

Tags: android, xml, apk, androguard

I tried to use androguard to analyze apk files, but some apk's AndroidManifest.xml do not show value directly, for example

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@7F0A02D1">
```

How can I retrieve the value of "@7F0A02D1" with androguard?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to get this value:

```
from androguard.core.bytecodes.apk import APK

a = APK(path_to_apk)    
r = a.get_android_resources()
location = int('7F0A02D1', 16)
resolved_strings = r.get_resolved_strings()
package_name = a.get_package()
value = resolved_strings.get(package_name, {}).get('DEFAULT', {}).get(location, '')
```

'DEFAULT' could be other values, check it out for yourself.